# jmeter report via email with a table embedded, not an attachment

Tags: email, jmeter, report

I would like to send jmeter load test results in an email generated either by jmeter or jenkins. The thing is that I don't want the report as an attachment, I want the report embedded in the email body so that somebody that receives the email doesn't need to open any attachment and neither needs to visit jenkins. I know that jmeter has pretty nice reports but I have not figured how to embed the data into the email itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your question in order to provide an answer, i.e. it is not clear which "report" do you mean.

1. If you want to send the report from JMeter - you can go for the following approach:

   - under [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) (it's being executed after all other thread groups)
   - using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) generate the report(s) of your choice using [Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) (the tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))
   - send the report(s) to the recipients of your choice using [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)
2. If you want to send the report using Jenkins you can go for the following:

   - generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
   - use Jenkins [Compress Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Compress+Artifacts+Plugin) to save the dashboard as .zip file
   - use Jenkins [Email ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to send the compressed dashboard to recepient(s)

Comment: Hi Dimitri. The jmrter dashboard HTML report has a table called statistics table. I wonder if somehow I can generate simmilar table and send it embedded in an email after tests are completed. Thanks